# How does one Determine the Distribution of a Statistic?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

The $F$ statistic looks like

$$ F = \frac{(\text{TSS}-\text{RSS})/(p-1)}{\text{RSS}/(n-p)},$$

How does one in general come up/design the right statistic to use for a given situation, and how
does one then determine its distribution? I assume one can use techniques maybe
like moment generating functions, or theorems dealing with convergence, e.g., CLT. or maybe expressing this ratio in terms of operations on statistics with already-known distributions, e.g., If $X$ is normal, then $ Z=\frac {x-\mu}{\sigma}$ is just a composition of a translation and a scaling , neither of which affect the distribution (other than by shifting and rescaling its parameters from $N( \mu, \sigma)$ to $N(0,1)$ ) Is this it? 
  I am trying to put myself inside of the head of the first person who decided to use the $F$ statistic to determine whether $H_0$ should be accepted or rejected, but I cannot see, I do not have a clue of how I would have gone about choosing a statistic to test for whether $m:=0$ in the regression line $y=mx+b$.
   I am interested , though, in the topic in general, not just for the $F$ statistic.
  Thanks for any ideas, references, etc.